# Getting parks in American Samoa from GeoNames

Tags: geonames

I have this query which does not return anything:

http://api.geonames.org/search?featureCode=PRK&username=genadinik&country=US&style=full&adminCode1=AS&maxRows=1000

Should I change it, or is American Samoa considered its own country?